# HTML loading before KO

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a page which has some KO scripts within it, now at the moment my 2 drop-downs which do
not have knockout are loading before the KO scripts meaning it looks really ugly, is there
a way i can make everything wait until everything is ready to show and then show?

Thanks any advice would be great?

Answer (score 1):

Use container to which you apply bindings with 'display: none' style.

```
<div style='display: none' id='container' data-bind='visible: true'>
</div>
```

Then use visible binding on the root of the view model like:

```
function MyViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  ...
  self.Loaded = true;
  ...
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(), document.getElementById('container'));
```

---

Update. As per @Jeroen's comment even this will serve:

```
<div style='display: none' id='container' data-bind='visible: true'>
</div>
```

Comment: +1. And even `style='display: none' data-bind='visible: true'` can help at times.

Comment: @Jeroen , thanks, good remark! I'll change my answer.